# Как лучше реализовать доставку данных в классы

Tags: android, kotlin, архитектура

Есть репозиторий настроек

```
interface SettingsRepositiry {
    fun get(): Single<Settings> //RxKotlin
}
```

Есть абстрактный маппер

```
interface Mapper {
    fun map(value: String): String
}
```

Есть реализация маппера

```
class MapperImpl(private val settingsRep: SettingsRepositiry) : Mapper {

    override fun map(value: String): String {
        val settings = settingsRep.get()//необходимо получить настройки
        return "$value ${settings.weight}" //условное использование настроек
    }
}
```

Код выше не будет работать..

Или можно было бы сделать такую реализацию

```
class MapperImpl @Inject constructor(private val settings: Settings) : Mapper {
    override fun map(value: String): String {
        return "$value ${settings.weight}" //условное использование настроек
    }
}
```

Код выше тоже непонятно как будет работать, т.к. необходимо перед инициализацией асинхронно получить `Settings`, а инициализация происходит при создании Фрагмента/активити через `Dagger`.

Другой пример. В одном из маппером используется `BitmapDiscriptor`, но ему необходимо получать настройки при генерации `Bitmap`

```
class MyMapper @Inject constructor(private val bitmapDescriptor: BitmapDescriptor) : Mapper {
    override fun map(value: Data): OtherData {
        val otherData = OtherData()
        otherData.bitmap = bitmapDescriptor.bitmapDescriptorFromVector(R.drawable.photo) //код условный.
        //....  
        return otherData
    }
}


class BitmapDescriptor @Inject constructor(private val context: Context, private val settings: Settings) {
    fun bitmapDescriptorFromVector(vectorResId: Int): BitmapDescriptor? {
        return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId)?.run {
            setBounds(0, 0, intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight)
            var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            draw(Canvas(bitmap))
            bitmap = bitmap.scale(width * settings.weight, height * settings.weight, false) //необходимо менять размер bitmap в соответствии с пользовательскими настройками
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }
}
```

Такой подход работал бы если получение настроек были бы синхронными, но что если они идут асинхронно?
Ну в принципе понятно, что нужно либо поменять на синхронное получение настроек либо нужно переделывать `BitmapDescriptor` и `Mapper"ы` чтобы на вход метода приходили параметры Settings.

Как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Если говорить про первый пример, то вы неправильно выстраиваете зависимости и ответственность классов. Маппер не должен зависеть от репозитория, так как его обязанность только преобразование данных. Он по хорошему вообще ничего не должен знать ни о чём и получать на вход метода преобразования все необходимые данные.

Репозиторий должен зависеть от маппера (получать его в конструкторе). Обязанность репозитория получить данные, не важно асинхронно или синхронно и уже после, применив маппер, их преобразовать и передать по назначению.

Во втором примере по сути всё тоже самое. BitmapDescriptor не должен зависеть от настроек, а должен получать их на вход метода bitmapDescriptorFromVector из класса MyMapper. Так же и MyMapper ничто про них знать не должен, а получать их будет на вход метода map из репозитория.

То как получать настройки вы должны решить сами, но уже в репозитории.